# How to create getters and setters for all sub-properties of a Vuex state property efficiently?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Let's say we have Vuex store with the following data:

### Vuex store

```js
state: {
  dialogs: {
    dialogName1: {
      value: false,
      data: {
        fileName: '',
        isValid: false,
        error: '',
        ... 10 more properties 
      }
    },
    dialogName2: {
      value: false,
      data: {
        type: '',
        isValid: false,
        error: '',
        ... 10 more properties
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Dialogs.vue

```html
<div v-if="dialogName1Value">
  <input 
    v-model="dialogName1DataFileName"
    :error="dialogName1DataIsValid"
    :error-text="dialogName1DataError"
  >

  <v-btn @click="dialogName1Value = false">
    close dialog
  </v-btn>
</div>
<!-- the other dialogs here -->
```

### Question

Let's say we need to modify some of these properties in `Dialogs.vue`.

What's the best practices for creating a getter and setter for every dialog property efficiently, without having to do it all manually like this:

```js
computed: {
  dialogName1Value: {
    get () {
      return this.$store.state.dialogs.dialogName1.value
    },
    set (value) {
      this.$store.commit('SET', { key: 'dialogs.dialogName1.value', value: value })
    }
  },
  dialogName1DataFileName: {
    get () {
      return this.$store.state.dialogs.dialogName1.data.fileName
    },
    set (value) {
      this.$store.commit('SET', { key: 'dialogs.dialogName1.data.fileName', value: value })
    }
  },
  dialogName1DataIsValid: {
    get () {
      return this.$store.state.dialogs.dialogName1.data.isValid
    },
    set (value) {
      this.$store.commit('SET', { key: 'dialogs.dialogName1.data.isValid', value: value })
    }
  },
  dialogName1DataIsError: {
    get () {
      return this.$store.state.dialogs.dialogName1.data.error
    },
    set (value) {
      this.$store.commit('SET', { key: 'dialogs.dialogName1.data.error', value: value })
    }
  },
  ... 10 more properties
```

And this is only 4 properties...

I suppose I could generate those computed properties programmatically in `created()`, but is that really the proper way to do it?

Are there obvious, commonly known solutions for this issue that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

`getters` can be made to take a parameter as an argument - this can be the 'part' of the underlying state you want to return. This is known as [Method-style access](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access). For example:

```
getFilename: (state) => (dialogName) => {
    return state.dialogs[dialogName].data.fileName
}
```

You can then call this getter as:

```
store.getters.getFilename('dialogName1')
```

Note that method style access doesn't provide the 'computed property' style caching that you get with property-style access.

Comment: Thanks for a solution. But how do I incorporate the setters into this? Isn't that gonna add even more boilerplate than just using computed `get(), set()` which already looks ridiculous, as you can see form the example

Comment: Vuex getters (note the difference from computed property getters) are effectively identical to computed properties. So you don't need computed properties with `get` and `set`, you just instead use `$store.get` and `$store.commit`

Answer (score 1):

For setting those things in only one central function you can use something like this:

```
<input 
  :value="dialogName1DataFileName"
  @input="update_inputs($event, 'fileName')">

// ...
methods:{
  update_inputs($event, whichProperty){
    this.$store.commit("SET_PROPERTIES", {newVal: $event.target.value, which:"whichProperty"})
  }
}
```

mutation handler:

```
// ..

mutations:{
  SET_PROPERTIES(state, payload){
    state.dialogName1.data[payload.which] = payload.newVal
  }
}
```

Let me explain more what we done above. First we change to v-model type to `:value` and `@input` base. Basically you can think, `:value` is `getter` and `@input` is `setter` for that property. Then we didn't commit in first place, we calling update_inputs function to commit because we should determine which inner property we will commit, so then we did send this data as a method parameter (for example above code is 'fileName') then, we commit this changes with new value of data and info for which property will change. You can make this logic into your whole code blocks and it will solved your problem.

And one more, if you want to learn more about this article will help you more:
https://pekcan.dev/v-model-using-vuex/

Comment: Thank you for a solution. I'm not sure how useful would this method be in my case though, it basically creates a more concise proxy method for the dynamic setters that I already have. I can already set all properties with it, e.g: `$store.commit('SET', { key: 'dialogs.dialogName1.data.fileName', value: value })`. I was looking for a more generalized approach. I decided to just automatically generate computed properties for all sub-properties of each dialog, now I can set properties in a more concise way, e.g: `dialogName1.data.fileName = 'name'` and `v-model="dialogName1.data.fileName"`